# Around what was the boundary set at Har Sinai?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashas-yisro, har-sinai

Shemos 19:12

> והגבלת את **העם** סביב לאמר השמרו לכם עלות בהר ונגע בקצהו כל הנגע בהר מות יומת
>
> And you shall set boundaries around **the nation** saying, "be careful not to go up the mountain..."

Shemos 19:23

> ויאמר משה אל יהוה לא יוכל העם לעלת אל הר סיני כי אתה העדתה בנו לאמר הגבל את **ההר** וקדשתו
>
> Moshe said "the nation can't come up, because you warned us to set boundaries around the **mountain**"

Was the mountain set off limits, or the Jewish people set off limits?

Answer (score 2):

[Haktav V'hakaballah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Tzvi_Mecklenburg) (Exod. 19:12) explains that the mountain was surrounded not the people. When it says והגבלת את העם this refers to making a boundary around the mountain, thus delineating the area where the people were restricted.

[R. Eliyahu Mizrahi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Mizrachi) similarly explains (Genesis 9:11) that the verse in Exodus (19:12)  doesn't mean to encircle the nation, but rather to make an encirclement, *for* the nation.

[Ibn Ezra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_ezra) (19:12) similarly [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.12?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en) that verse 12 also means encircling the mountain; not the people.

[Netsiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naftali_Zvi_Yehuda_Berlin), however, explains ([Haamek Davar 19:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.19.12?lang=bi&p2=Haamek_Davar_on_Exodus.19.12.1&lang2=bi)) that the two verses refer to two different boundaries. While verse 23 refers to encircling the mountain, verse 12 refers to delineations among the people; Aaron in the front, then the kohanim by rank, then great Yisraelim, then the rest of the men, then the woman and children.

Comment: See also the start of the intro to the _Haamek Davar_.